# Observer Pattern with an Observer observing multiple Subjects

Tags: php, object-oriented, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Is the below a good solution for an observer to monitor multiple subjects. My only fear is that if an observer was monitoring a wide range of subjects then the update method could get quite large checking each instance to see what type it is but I can't think of another way to implement this:

**Journalist Subject**

```
    class Journalist implements SplSubject {

    protected $observers;
    protected $name;
    protected $story;

    public function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->observers = new SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function attach( SplObserver $observer ) {
        $this->observers->attach( $observer );
    }

    public function detach( SplObserver $observer ) {
        $this->observers->detach( $observer );
    }

    public function notify() {
        foreach( $this->observers as $observer ) {
            $observer->update( $this );
        }
    }

    public function addStory( $story ) {
        $this->story = $story;
        $this->notify();
    }

    public function getStory() {
        return $this->story;
    }

    public function addName( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

**Website Subject**

```
    class Website implements SplSubject {

    protected $observers;
    protected $website;
    protected $webPage;

    public function __construct( $website ) {
        $this->website = $website;
        $this->observers = new SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function attach( SplObserver $observer ) {
        $this->observers->attach( $observer );
    }

    public function detach( SplObserver $observer ) {
        $this->observers->detach( $observer );
    }

    public function notify() {
        foreach( $this->observers as $observer ) {
            $observer->update( $this );
        }
    }

    public function addWebPage( $webPage ) {
        $this->webPage = $webPage;
        $this->notify();
    }

    public function getWebPage() {
        return $this->webPage;
    }

    public function addWebsite( $website ) {
        $this->website = $website;
    }

    public function getWebsite() {
        return $this->website;
    }

}
```

**The Sun Observer**

```
class TheSun implements SplObserver {

    public function update( SplSubject $observable ) {

        if( $observable instanceof Journalist )
            echo __CLASS__ . ' noticed that the journalist ' . $observable->getName() . ' said: ' . $observable->getStory() . '<br />';

        if( $observable instanceof Website )
            echo __CLASS__ . ' noticed that the website ' . $observable->getWebsite() . ' uploaded a page to: ' . $observable->getWebPage() . '<br />';

    }

}
```

**The Mirror Observer**

```
class TheMirror implements SplObserver {

    public function update( SplSubject $observable ) {

        if( $observable instanceof Journalist )
            echo __CLASS__ . ' noticed that the journalist ' . $observable->getName() . ' said: ' . $observable->getStory() . '<br />';

        if( $observable instanceof Website )
            echo __CLASS__ . ' noticed that the website ' . $observable->getWebsite() . ' uploaded a page to: ' . $observable->getWebPage() . '<br />';

    }

}
```

**The Guardian Observer**

```
class TheGuardian implements SplObserver {

    public function update( SplSubject $observable ) {

        if( $observable instanceof Journalist )
            echo __CLASS__ . ' noticed that the journalist ' . $observable->getName() . ' said: ' . $observable->getStory() . '<br />';

        if( $observable instanceof Website )
            echo __CLASS__ . ' noticed that the website ' . $observable->getWebsite() . ' uploaded a page to: ' . $observable->getWebPage() . '<br />';

    }

}
```

**Code**

```
$Journalist = new Journalist( 'John' );
$Website = new Website( 'Stack Overflow' );

$TheSun = new TheSun;
$TheMirror = new TheMirror;
$TheGuardian = new TheGuardian;

$Journalist->attach( $TheSun );
$Journalist->attach( $TheMirror );
$Journalist->attach( $TheGuardian );

$Website->attach( $TheSun );
$Website->attach( $TheMirror );
$Website->attach( $TheGuardian );

$Journalist->addStory( 'Knock, Knock' );
$Website->addWebPage( 'http://www.hello.com' );

$Journalist->detach( $TheSun );
$Journalist->detach( $TheMirror );
$Website->detach( $TheGuardian );

$Journalist->addStory( 'Whos There?' );
$Website->addWebPage( 'http://www.goodbye.com' );
```

The code should run exactly as is above. Any advice would be very welcome.

A second question I have is what if I wanted to notify the observers of more than one different action, for example some services might want to know in the example above if a Website or Journalists name has changed separately to if they have posted a new article, how could this be best accomplished?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Traits**

First of all, we have to remove duplications caused by the implementation of the SplObject interface. We have here a great case for a trait: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php.

Here is a refactoring using a trait (the rest is unchanged):

```
<?php

trait Subject
{

    private $observer = null;

    public function attach(SplObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->getObservers()->attach($observer);
    }

    public function detach(SplObserver $observer)
    {
        $this->getObservers()->detach($observer);
    }

    public function notify()
    {
        foreach ($this->getObserver as $observer) {
            $observer->update($this);
        }
    }

    protected function getObserver()
    {
        if (is_null($this->observer)) $this->observer = new SplObjectStorage();
        return $this->observer;
    }
}


class Journalist implements SplSubject
{

    use Subject;

    protected $name;
    protected $story;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function addStory($story)
    {
        $this->story = $story;
        $this->notify();
    }

    public function getStory()
    {
        return $this->story;
    }

    public function addName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}

Website Subject

class Website implements SplSubject
{

    use Subject;

    protected $website;
    protected $webPage;

    public function __construct($website)
    {
        $this->website = $website;
    }

    public function addWebPage($webPage)
    {
        $this->webPage = $webPage;
        $this->notify();
    }

    public function getWebPage()
    {
        return $this->webPage;
    }

    public function addWebsite($website)
    {
        $this->website = $website;
    }
}
```

**Dedicated subclass**

In order to increase the separation of concern and the reusability of your code, I advise you to create specific subclasses for your subjects:

```
class JournalistAsSubject extends Journalist implements SplSubject 
{
    use Subject;

    public function addStory($story)
    {
        parent::addStory($story);
        $this->notify();
    }
}

class Journalist
{
    protected $name;
    protected $story;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function addStory($story)
    {
        $this->story = $story;
    }

    public function getStory()
    {
        return $this->story;
    }

    public function addName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

---

**The dispatcher**

But there is a better way to separate concerns: the use of a dispatcher:

```
class EventDispatcher
{
    private $listeners = [];
    public function addListener($event_type, $listener)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($event_type, $this->listeners)) $this->listener[$event_type] = [];
        $this->listeners[$event_type][] = $listener;
    }

    public function dispatch($event_type, $event)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($event_type, $this->listeners)) throw new \InvalidArgumentException($event_type.' does not exists');
        foreach($this->listeners[$event_type] as $listener) {
            $listener->update($event);
        }
    }
}

class ArtclePublishedEvent
{
    public function __construct(Author $author, $title, $content)
    {
        $this->author = $author;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getAuthor(){ return $this->author; }
    public function getTitle(){ return $this->title; }
    public function getContent(){ return $this->content; }
}
```

So we have now very simple entities:

```
class Author
{
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(){ return $this->name; }
}

class NewsRoom
{
    public function update($event)
    {
        return $event->author->name.' as written a new article called: "'.$event->title.'"';
    }
}
```

*Note: in a real software, the article has to be a separate entity which is injected in the event object*

And so we can use the whole system like this:

```
$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
$dispatcher->addListener('article.publish', new NewsRoom());

$event = new ArticlePublishedEvent(new Author('John'), 'a fairy tale', 'some very short content');
$dispatcher->dispatch('article.publish', $event);
```

Comment: Thanks lilobase for some great tips, especially in regards the Events Dispatcher. I always kind of disregard traits in my mind as it's been drilled in to me that they are just a glorified copy and paste, however I do believe they have a use here...

Comment: I give you an insight to know when to use specific OOP construction in order to maintain what we called the orthogonality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science.     
    
Between two of your entity:    
- is a = inheritance    
- belong to = aggregation    
- has a = composition    
- behave like = trait

Comment: Based on the relation between two entities you can have: `is a = inheritance`, `belong to = aggregation`, `has a = composition`, `behave like = trait`. For example here your *Author behaves like a subject* (=trait) and an *Article has an Author* (=composition). Another example can be: an *invoice line belong to an invoice* (=aggregation).

Comment: Hi lilo, thanks very much for the clarification. I also have one further question in regards the Events Dispatcher and MVC or frameworks, where should the listeners be added (is it in a global place or in controllers, models etc.?)

Comment: In the service layer, a service between your model and the controller.

Comment: I see I still have much to learn...!